# Why is certificate request invalid from Exchange 2019?

Tags: exchange, certificate, certificate-authority, xca

I am creating a cert request in powershell on an exchange 2019 server as follows:

```
$binrequest = New-ExchangeCertificate -Server "exchange" -BinaryEncoded -GenerateRequest -FriendlyName "Exchange Certificate 2023" -PrivateKeyExportable $true -SubjectName "c=CA, o=MYDOMAIN, ou=IT, cn=*.MYDOMAIN.COM" -DomainName  exchange.MYDOMAIN.COM,autodiscover.MYDOMAIN.COM  
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('d:\temporary\exchange2023.req', [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($binrequest))
```

(I have obfoscated my real domain name with MYDOMAIN.COM.)  I then move the cert request to my CA (I run XCA 2.5.0), import it and try to generate the cert.  However, when I try to sign the above request XCA reports:

```
"The verification of the certificate request failed.  The rollout should be aborted"
```

If I check the properties of the cert request in XCA I see:

```
Signature: Failed (sha1WithRSAEncryption)
```

Is Exch2019 generating an invalid request?  Or is this normal for a request since it is not signed?  How do I diagnose this?

Comment: All CSRs are signed. You requested a binary (DER) request but then tried to treat it as Unicode, which it is not, so this mangles and destroys parts of the data, making the signature invalid. For a binary request write it as binary [as shown in example 5 here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-exchangecertificate?view=exchange-ps#example-5)

Comment: This was fixed in September 2021 in Exchange Server 2019 CU11.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/cumulative-update-11-for-exchange-server-2019-kb5005334-93fc6a41-faa4-424e-9dcb-27081360872b

Comment: But my Exchange version is 15.02.1118.009 (CU 12)...unless this bug returned

Answer (score 0):

[Exchange Server 2019 and 2016 certificates created during setup use SHA-1 hash](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/exchange-server-2019-and-2016-certificates-created-during-setup-use-sha-1-hash-kb5006983-83282c37-1cbf-4a9d-b6a6-8390fac42eeb)